# How to insert html tag with sed?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

I have `HTML` document with this content

```
<!--START-->
Some unimportant content - line1
Some unimportant content - line2
Some unimportant content - ...
<!--END-->
```

I want to replace the content between comments *START-END*

*Desired output*

```
<!--START-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
<!--END-->
```

I know how to replace the content between comments with `sed` unix command, but I have problems to replace it with `script` tag.

Here is the command

```
REPLACEMENT="<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"somefile.js\"><\/script>"
STARTTAG="START"
ENDTAG="END"
EXPRESSION='/'"$STARTTAG"'/{p;:a;N;/'"$ENDTAG"'/!ba;s/.*\n/'"$REPLACEMENT"'\n/};p'
sed -n $EXPRESSION -i target.html
```

When I run it, it ends with the error `unterminated s' command`. There is probably problem with space in `REPLACEMENT`, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Just a thought: Rather than trying to _replace_ the text using _substitution_, could you simply not _insert_ the desired text between your STARTTAG and ENDTAG?

Comment: For pity's sake use `sed -n "$EXPRESSION"` with double quotes around the variable reference.  You have blanks in the 'replacement' text, so you must quote the argument.  However, I always worry when I see any backslashes around; it indicates trouble looming.  For example, the whole of the replacement string should be in single quotes; you would then need fewer backslashes.  You can also use characters other than `/` to mark either `s///` operations or searches (`s@from@to@`, for example, or `\@from@,\@to@p`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e "/$STARTTAG/p;/$ENDTAG/h;/$STARTTAG/,/$ENDTAG/c$REPLACEMENT" -e 'x;/./{p;z};x' file
```

This prints the `STARTTAG` when it is first encounterd and saves the `ENDTAG` in the hold space to be printed following the changed lines.

N.B. This only works when the `ENDTAG` is not the last line in the file!

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is only one line between your tags START and END.

Try this with GNU sed:

```
REPLACEMENT="<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"somefile.js\"><\/script>"
STARTTAG="START"
ENDTAG="END"
EXPRESSION="/$STARTTAG/,/$ENDTAG/{/$STARTTAG/{p;d};/$ENDTAG/{p;d};s/.*/$REPLACEMENT/}"

sed -i "$EXPRESSION" target.html
```

Output (target.html):

```
<!--START-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="somefile.js"></script>
<!--END-->
```

---

or:

```
REPLACEMENT="<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"somefile.js\"><\/script>"
STARTTAG="START"
ENDTAG="END"
EXPRESSION="/$STARTTAG/p;s/.*$ENDTAG.*/$REPLACEMENT\n&/p"   
sed -i -n "$EXPRESSION" file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but between comments is more lines. But basically, it is usable. I made it in two phases, firstly I can replace multiline text with any text, and then replace it with your solution.

Comment: I've added a more elegant answer which can handle multiple lines between your tags.